# Ember js table component

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I made a very simple table component. It takes a model, and builds a table from it.

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/raqomebeqi/1

Since its very primitive and has hard-coded property names, I decided to make an in-component representation of the model, to sort, filter the content of the table. It also allows to show just certain columns from the bounded model. (columns property)

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/raqomebeqi/2

The problem: It doesn't react to the changes of the model anymore. In the first example If I hit the 'change' button, it takes the first record, and set a new name. One can see the change in the table. In the second case Ember inspector shows the change of the name, but the table shows the old value.

I know I could do

```
data: Ember.computed('model.@each.name', function(){
  //...
})
```

to monitor the changes on the name, but it is not very dynamic. How could I make my `data` react to each and every change on the **model**?

Answer (score 0):

If you want your data to react on every change, you could do:

```
data: Ember.computed('model', function(){
    //...
})
```

**UPDATE:**

This is not working

Comment: no it won't work. Only if the whole model is changed out. If only one property changes, it won't fire.

Comment: And in case of `model.@each`?

Comment: try it out: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/wogikazobe/1/edit <spoiler> it wont work </spoiler>.

Comment: You are right, I was under the impression that this would work. Seems there is no way to do this easily.

Comment: yeah I couldn't find  a clean and easy solution. Maybe I try to make a nested component: table->row->cell. I think it could help if row only observes its cells. Maybe im dead wrong